# Exception from validator is not shown when using cardano-serialization-lib

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program

I have this simple validator:

```
newtype BreedConfig = BreedConfig
    { feeAddr  :: PubKeyHash
    } deriving (Generic, ToJSON, FromJSON)

PlutusTx.makeIsDataIndexed ''BreedConfig [('BreedConfig, 0)]
PlutusTx.makeLift ''BreedConfig

data BreedDatum = BreedDatum
    { owner       :: !PubKeyHash
    , deadline    :: !POSIXTime
    , currency1   :: !CurrencySymbol
    , token1      :: !TokenName
    , currency2   :: !CurrencySymbol
    , token2      :: !TokenName
    , serviceFee  :: !Plutus.Integer
    , serviceDFee :: !Plutus.Integer
    } deriving (Generic, ToJSON, FromJSON)

instance Eq BreedDatum where
    {-# INLINABLE (==) #-}
    a == b = (owner    a == owner    b) &&
             (deadline     a == deadline     b) &&
             (currency1    a == currency1  b) &&
             (token1       a == token1     b) &&
             (currency2    a == currency2  b) &&
             (token2       a == token2  b) &&
             (serviceFee   a == serviceFee  b) &&
             (serviceDFee  a == serviceDFee  b)

PlutusTx.makeIsDataIndexed ''BreedDatum [('BreedDatum, 0)]
PlutusTx.makeLift ''BreedDatum


data BreedAction = Claim | Cancel
    deriving Show

PlutusTx.makeIsDataIndexed ''BreedAction [('Claim, 0), ('Cancel, 1)]
PlutusTx.makeLift ''BreedAction

{-# INLINABLE breedDatum #-}
breedDatum :: TxOut -> (DatumHash -> Maybe Datum) -> Maybe BreedDatum
breedDatum o f = do
    dh <- txOutDatum o
    Datum d <- f dh
    PlutusTx.fromBuiltinData d

{-# INLINABLE mkbreedValidator #-}
mkbreedValidator :: BreedConfig -> BreedDatum -> BreedAction -> ScriptContext -> Bool
mkbreedValidator cfg breedDat r ctx = case r of
        Claim    -> traceIfFalse "No rights to perform this action (claim)" (txSignedBy (scriptContextTxInfo ctx) (owner breedDat)) &&
                    traceIfFalse "Fee not paid" (checkFee (serviceFee breedDat)) &&
                    traceIfFalse "deadline not reached" deadlineReached
        Cancel  -> traceIfFalse "No rights to perform this action" (txSignedBy (scriptContextTxInfo ctx) (owner breedDat))

  where
    info :: TxInfo
    info = scriptContextTxInfo ctx

    sig :: PubKeyHash
    sig = case txInfoSignatories info of
            [pubKeyHash] -> pubKeyHash

    deadlineReached :: Bool
    deadlineReached = contains (from $ deadline breedDat) $ txInfoValidRange info

    checkFee :: Integer -> Bool
    checkFee srvfee = fromInteger (Ada.getLovelace (Ada.fromValue (valuePaidTo info $ feeAddr cfg))) == fromInteger srvfee
                                  

data Breed
instance Scripts.ValidatorTypes Breed where
    type instance DatumType Breed    = BreedDatum
    type instance RedeemerType Breed = BreedAction


typedBreedValidator :: BreedConfig -> Scripts.TypedValidator Breed
typedBreedValidator bc = Scripts.mkTypedValidator @Breed
    ($$(PlutusTx.compile [|| mkbreedValidator ||]) `PlutusTx.applyCode` PlutusTx.liftCode bc)
    $$(PlutusTx.compile [|| wrap ||])
  where
    wrap = Scripts.wrapValidator @BreedDatum @BreedAction


breedValidator :: BreedConfig -> Validator
breedValidator = Scripts.validatorScript . typedBreedValidator

breedValidatorHash :: BreedConfig -> ValidatorHash
breedValidatorHash = validatorHash . breedValidator

breedScript :: BreedConfig -> Plutus.Script
breedScript = Ledger.unValidatorScript . breedValidator

breedScriptAsShortBs :: BreedConfig -> SBS.ShortByteString
breedScriptAsShortBs = SBS.toShort . LB.toStrict . serialise . breedScript

apiBreedScript :: BreedConfig -> PlutusScript PlutusScriptV1
apiBreedScript = PlutusScriptSerialised . breedScriptAsShortBs
```

When I test it using cardano-cli everything works, so when I try to retrieve tokens before deadline I'm getting exception from validator.

When I use the same smart contract code from webpage I'm not getting the expected error **"deadline not reached"**

In the webpage I take latest block and from it I extract time and add to it 5 minutes and use this as parameter deadline in datum

```
const deadline = (await getLatestPosixTime()) + 300000;
breedingParams.deadline = deadline.toString();
```

Next if I try to retrieve the locked tokens before five minutes have elapsed I'm not seeing nice **CEK exception "deadline not reached"** that should be raised from validator.

Instead I'm seeing:

```
  ""transaction submit error ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraAlonzo (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (UtxosFailure (ValidationTagMismatch (IsValid True) (FailedUnexpectedly [PlutusFailure \"\\nThe 3 arg plutus script (PlutusScript PlutusV1 ScriptHash \\\"0b71d943b18479d4742ea625e06e249a79cadcb4fa8c5dcf86ae64b4\\\") fails.\\nCekError An error has occurred:  User error:\\nThe provided Plutus code called 'error'.\\n
The data is: Constr 0 [B \\\"_\\\\SYN\\\\DC4\\\\153C\\\\217\\\\132\\\\182\\\\228\\\\158\\\\169\\\\149\\\\193R\\\\230z3\\\\a\\\\DC1\\\\SO\\\\219q\\\\190\\\\ACK\\\\131\\\\221\\\\167^\\\",I 1645699355000,B \\\"\\\\230\\\\ESC\\\\252\\\\DLEc8\\\\237J\\\\235\\\\169\\\\&062O\\\\190\\\\168\\\\NAK\\\\SI\\\\217u\\\\SI\\\\207\\\\252\\\\161\\\\205\\\\159\\\\SUB\\\\EM\\\",B \\\"DinoSavior00537\\\",B \\\"\\\\230\\\\ESC\\\\252\\\\DLEc8\\\\237J\\\\235\\\\169\\\\&062O\\\\190\\\\168\\\\NAK\\\\SI\\\\217u\\\\SI\\\\207\\\\252\\\\161\\\\205\\\\159\\\\SUB\\\\EM\\\",B \\\"DinoSavior01301\\\",I 10000000,I 1000]\\nThe redeemer is: Constr 0 []\\nThe context is:\\n
Purpose: Spending (TxOutRef {txOutRefId = 7117be7c6ce8ec60e5833c3c710326f9b42c00b45bd45bd2fdce3a8024a1e290, txOutRefIdx = 0})\\nTxInfo:\\n  TxId: ae79dfa4ab0a987942bc281ce40fd22b4c2aee58eb564e439974c40856e83a2f\\n  Inputs: [ 7117be7c6ce8ec60e5833c3c710326f9b42c00b45bd45bd2fdce3a8024a1e290!0 -> - Value (Map [(,Map [(\\\"\\\",13000000)]),(e61bfc106338ed4aeba93036324fbea8150fd9750fcffca1cd9f1a19,Map [(\\\"DinoSavior00537\\\",1),(\\\"DinoSavior01301\\\",1)])]) addressed to\\n                                                                                    ScriptCredential: 0b71d943b18479d4742ea625e06e249a79cadcb4fa8c5dcf86ae64b4 (no staking credential)\\n          , 7117be7c6ce8ec60e5833c3c710326f9b42c00b45bd45bd2fdce3a8024a1e290!1 -> - Value (Map [(,Map [(\\\"\\\",29337196)]),
(e61bfc106338ed4aeba93036324fbea8150fd9750fcffca1cd9f1a19,Map [(\\\"DinoSavior04792\\\",1),(\\\"DinoSavior05352\\\",1),(\\\"DinoSavior07962\\\",1),(\\\"DinoSavior08352\\\",1),(\\\"DinoSavior09109\\\",1)]),(ee8e37676f6ebb8e031dff493f88ff711d24aa68666a09d61f1d3fb3,Map [(\\\"Cryptodino02704\\\",1),(\\\"Cryptodino05426\\\",1),(\\\"Cryptodino05943\\\",1),(\\\"Cryptodino06553\\\",1),(\\\"Cryptodino06853\\\",1)])]) addressed to\\n                                                                                    PubKeyCredential: 5f16149943d984b6e49ea995c152e67a3307110edb71be0683dda75e (StakingHash PubKeyCredential: 309275ebc497184c163de20271e1af63d6e7b1e03f4b6cea0af3fd4a) ]\\n  Outputs: [ - Value (Map [(,Map [(\\\"\\\",3000000)]),
(e61bfc106338ed4aeba93036324fbea8150fd9750fcffca1cd9f1a19,Map [(\\\"DinoSavior00537\\\",1),(\\\"DinoSavior01301\\\",1)])]) addressed to\\n               PubKeyCredential: 5f16149943d984b6e49ea995c152e67a3307110edb71be0683dda75e (StakingHash PubKeyCredential: 309275ebc497184c163de20271e1af63d6e7b1e03f4b6cea0af3fd4a)\\n           , - Value (Map [(,Map [(\\\"\\\",10000000)])]) addressed to\\n               PubKeyCredential: e2a206cf1f33c8bb90722b6fd92f747911485954f0562faae0b16bc0 (StakingHash PubKeyCredential: d55b8648692398368392f24ad16d56235d1b514ed616b09cdb7281b2)\\n           , - Value (Map [(,Map [(\\\"\\\",28294183)]),(e61bfc106338ed4aeba93036324fbea8150fd9750fcffca1cd9f1a19,Map [(\\\"DinoSavior04792\\\",1),(\\\"DinoSavior05352\\\",1),(\\\"DinoSavior07962\\\",1),(\\\"DinoSavior08352\\\",1),(\\\"DinoSavior09109\\\",1)]),(ee8e37676f6ebb8e031dff493f88ff711d24aa68666a09d61f1d3fb3,Map [(\\\"Cryptodino02704\\\",1),(\\\"Cryptodino05426\\\",1),(\\\"Cryptodino05943\\\",1),(\\\"Cryptodino06553\\\",1),(\\\"Cryptodino06853\\\",1)])]) addressed to\\n               PubKeyCredential: 5f16149943d984b6e49ea995c152e67a3307110edb71be0683dda75e (StakingHash PubKeyCredential: 309275ebc497184c163de20271e1af63d6e7b1e03f4b6cea0af3fd4a) ]\\n  Fee: Value (Map [(,Map [(\\\"\\\",1043013)])])\\n  Value minted: Value (Map [])\\n  DCerts: []\\n  Wdrl: []\\n  Valid range: [ POSIXTime 1645699329000 , +\\8734)\\n  Signatories: 
[5f16149943d984b6e49ea995c152e67a3307110edb71be0683dda75e]\\n  Datums: [ ( 1dbcbc38286af4f5f77fea28a01a76c7c53dc4eaaa27f2b1197e183d0741350c\\n          , <\\\"_\\\\SYN\\\\DC4\\\\153C\\\\217\\\\132\\\\182\\\\228\\\\158\\\\169\\\\149\\\\193R\\\\230z3\\\\a\\\\DC1\\\\SO\\\\219q\\\\190\\\\ACK\\\\131\\\\221\\\\167^\\\",\\n          1645699355000,\\n          \\\"\\\\230\\\\ESC\\\\252\\\\DLEc8\\\\237J\\\\235\\\\169\\\\&062O\\\\190\\\\168\\\\NAK\\\\SI\\\\217u\\\\SI\\\\207\\\\252\\\\161\\\\205\\\\159\\\\SUB\\\\EM\\\",\\n          \\\"DinoSavior00537\\\",\\n          \\\"\\\\230\\\\ESC\\\\252\\\\DLEc8\\\\237J\\\\235\\\\169\\\\&062O\\\\190\\\\168\\\\NAK\\\\SI\\\\217u\\\\SI\\\\207\\\\252\\\\161\\\\205\\\\159\\\\SUB\\\\EM\\\",\\n          \\\"DinoSavior01301\\\",\\n          10000000,\\n          1000> ) ]\\n\" \"some very long string - maybe transaction body
```

However using the same code in the webpage if I try to redeem my tokens after 5 minutes everything works, I'm able to retrieve them from smart contract.
I'm passing the deadline as an integer to the Datum.